# How to handle authentication data correctly through the whole app

Tags: objective-c

I've seen a lot of posts about this subject and the morre I read about that the more i am confused. I will explain what I want and I hope you can give me a good answer.

I have created a loginviewcontroller to a remote database. When the authentication was successful, the server returns the userID and a token. 
Now I want to keep this two variables the whole time, because i need them everytime i connect to the remote database (thats allways & everywhere).

So what is the best way to handle this.

I thought about a singleton but some people say its good and some say its bad..
Maybe the singleton solution is colpetely wrong, for what I want to do…?

So please tell me what is the best way to keep authentication data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1), particularly if you are storing authentication information persistently.

Comment: I do store username and password in my keychain service. But is it also a good way to store the userID and the token in it? I'm asking that because the token has an expiration date, so it is no really persistently.

Answer (score 1):

I have a custom subclass of `NSMutableURLRequest` where I do all kinds of auth and other stuff specific to my server. I keep a couple of static NSStrings in that module. (It's even a little naughtier than a singleton, but take that singleton advice with a grain of salt...Singletons aren't satanic, they're just discouraged). Sometimes you really need to have just one of something.

Comment: So whenever you connect to your remote db you go through your subclass where those vars are "saved"? is that waht you mean?

Comment: Yes.  I persist on the auth call, then lazily read the next time the class is used.  Keychain services is a good answer, too.